# double quotes makes text dissappear, why?

Tags: php, html

Whenever the texts value has double-quotes, everything behind and including the double-quotes dissappear.

Ex: `Nice bmw m3 with 19" wheels` BECOMES `Nice bmw m3 with 19` the part after the double-quotes is skipped.

Is there anyway around this?

About the code below: This is for a form on a php page, so when the form is submitted to itself the value of the input remains unchanged, so the user doesn't have to fill in everything again whenever form is submitted to self.

```
<input style="width:300px;" type="text" name="annonsera_headline" id="annonsera_headline" value="<?php echo @$_POST['annonsera_headline'];?>">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `"` ends the value of the html attribute.

Use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
value="<?php echo htmlentities(@$_POST['annonsera_headline']);?>">
```

It is not advisable to write values from `$_POST` or `$_GET` without using at least one of the above functions as otherwise it allows people to construct a URL that alters the HTML on your page.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to sanitize the value with [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Comment: check the comment above, do you know the answer to that? I am using utf-8 on every document so far. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
   ... value = "htmlentities(<?=$_POST['annonsera_headline']?>)"
```